# varnish cache storage

Tags: varnish

I'm trying to (re)build a VM that will be running Varnish Cache. One of the issues that I've had in the past, is running out of space (allocated space was ~10G).

I guess what I'm really confused about is how Varnish uses space. As soon as I start varnish it creates a file which is (from what I assume) is equivalent to size of your memory (which is in my case 4G) yet later on varnish end up using more space...

So what I'm trying to understand is how properly I should allocate space. Maybe some advises, best practices in general.

Comment: Which storage settings were you using?

Comment: I'm using file storage, I'm considering moving that file into ram disk and have same file but on ram disk to increase performance.

Comment: Right, but what specific settings are in place for the `-s` flag of your `varnishd` command?  That should tell us whether it's behaving properly in terms of storage behavior or not.

Comment: -s file,/var/lib/varnish/varnish_storage.bin,1G

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK there was a memory leak in version 3.0.0: are you perhaps hitting it?

Rather than using a ramdisk, I would simply change the varnishd option to "malloc", for example (change the size to something more useful, of course...)

```
  -s malloc,1G
```

BTW, even if the VM is dedicated to varnish, I would not allocate more than 80% of the RAM to the cache.

Comment: I just reconfigured my VM (REDHAT6) (now it looks like this: /usr/sbin/varnishd -P /var/run/varnish.pid -a :80 -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl -T 127.0.0.1:6082 -t 120 -w 1,1000,120 -u varnish -g varnish -S /etc/varnish/secret -s malloc,2G). VM has 6G of RAM, 2 of them allocated to Varnish.

Comment: I still seeing files in /var/lib/varnish/$HOSTNAME$/vcl.*.so & _.vsm

Comment: They should be (I am not 100% sure) the compiled rules and the log